# Does powershell have a way to handle calling a command with multiple parameter sets?

Tags: powershell

To be clear, I dont mean my command needs to be accepting multiple parameter sets, it needs to call a function that has multiple parameter sets.

My script

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='NamedCreds')]
    [PSCredential] $Credential,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='NamedCreds')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='DefaultCreds')]
    [string] $Url,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='NamedCreds')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='DefaultCreds')]
    [string] $Path,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='DefaultCreds')]
    [switch] $UseDefaultCredentials
)


#repeating this if block gets tedious
if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -ieq "NamedCreds")
{
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -OutFile $Path -Credential $Credential
}
else
{
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -OutFile $Path -UseDefaultCredentials
}

#do something with result
```

I'd like to avoid the "if parameter set name, else" conditionals that can end up littering the script. I've read about "splatting" but the examples for it explain it as a way to avoid scrolling to the right for long parameter lists, and don't cover parameter sets or optional parameters. Is there a way to call other commands and properly deal with optional params and param sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splatting is (sort of) the answer to this.

You need your conditionals to determine which parameters to pass. You can use them to *build* the hashtable and then pass it once.

For what you're trying to do, it might make more sense to rename your `-Url` parameter to `-Uri`, and `$Path` to `$OutFile` (you can always add an alias if you like the other name better), and then splat `$PSBoundParameters` directly:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='NamedCreds')]
    [PSCredential] $Credential,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='NamedCreds')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='DefaultCreds')]
    [Alias('Url')]
    [string] $Uri,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='NamedCreds')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='DefaultCreds')]
    [Alias('Path')]
    [string] $OutFile,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='DefaultCreds')]
    [switch] $UseDefaultCredentials
)


    $result = Invoke-RestMethod @PSBoundParameters
}
```

---

Going to address your comment here:

> This was an abbreviated example, there are usually more parameters
>   than that, as well as variables that are derived while the script is
>   executing that get passed into the command getting called. Is that
>   going to change this example?

Yeah, unfortunately directly using `$PSBoundParameters` like that works great, until it doesn't, which is usually quicker than you think (there are issues with optional parameters, certain automatic parameters, etc.).

What it really means is that: when you have conditions, you probably can't avoid conditionals.

When it starts to get complex like that, ignore the parameter sets, and just test every parameter except the ones that are mandatory or have default values (in all sets).

I just noticed you're naming every set on some; you don't need to do that. If the content of the `[Parameter()]` attribute is the same in every set then you can just use a single `[Parameter()]` attribute with no set named; I'm going to change your example below to reflect that.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='NamedCreds')]
    [PSCredential] $Credential,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [Alias('Url')]
    [string] $Uri,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $Path,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName='DefaultCreds')]
    [switch] $UseDefaultCredentials
)

    $params = @{
        Uri = $Uri
        Path = $Path
    }

    if ($Credential) {
        $params.Credential = $Credential
    }

    if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('UseDefaultCredentials')) {
        $params.UseDefaultCredentials = $UseDefaultCredentials
    }

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod @params

}
```

This is the pattern I typically use. Build a hashtable, then splat it once.

There are some subtleties to note so I will break this down further.

```
$params = @{
    Uri = $Uri
    OutFile = $Path
}
```

Here you create the `[hashtable]`. At the same time you can populate any members that will always be present. `Uri` and `Path` are mandatory paramrters in every parameter set, so essentially the code can't get here unless they have values (or to be more precise; in any condition, they cannot be omitted from the params you pass to `Invoke-RestMethod`).

If you don't have any of those parameters, then just make it empty `$params = @{}`.

Note that for `$Path` we made the key `OutFile` to match its name in the cmdlet that will be called (so you can have your own param names this way).

```
if ($Credential) {
    $params.Credential = $Credential
}
```

Pretty easy; test the param for truthiness. If there's something there, you add it to `$params`.

```
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('UseDefaultCredentials')) {
    $params.UseDefaultCredentials = $UseDefaultCredentials
}
```

Here's one of those special cases. If we use a basic conditional check instead:

```
if ($UseDefaultCredentials) {
    $params.UseDefaultCredentials = $UseDefaultCredentials
}
```

Then we have a slight problem, because you can call switch parameters with explicit values like this: `Invoke-RestMethod -UseDefaultCredentials:$false`. If you use the simple conditional, you won't be passing this through, but by checking if it's bound, you will check that the parameter was specified, no matter what its value is.

You don't always have to know; you may not want to support calling the switch parameter explicitly with false, in which case go ahead and do a simple check.

Also note that when you specify a parameter is `Mandatory`, you are also implicitly not allowing certain falsey values. A `Mandatory` `[String]` doesn't allow an empty string or `$null`. Array parameters don't allow empty arrays. You have to explicitly enable them with other attributes, like `[AllowEmptyString()]`. If you do this, simple checks don't work for those either because then you aren't passing through the real value; this is another instance where checking `$PSBoundParameters` is helpful.

The other thing you *can* do with a switch parameter is just always cast it to `[bool]` and put it in the hashtable:

```
$params.UseDefaultCredentials = $UseDefaultCredentials -as [bool]
# or, during initialization
$params = @{
    Uri = $Uri
    UseDefaultCredentials = $UseDefaultCredentials -as [bool]
}
```

This can only be done with switches that are not part of a parameter set, because otherwise you will be supplying it to the called command, even when it wasn't on your function, and that may cause invalid parameter sets to be chosen.

---

Other things you could do:

Use `switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)` instead of lots of `if`s, if alternating on the set is more important (like if some of your calculated values rely on the set more than any one specific param).

Start with bound parameters and modify them:

```
$params = $PSBoundParameters.Clone()

$params.OutFile = $params.Path
$params.Remove('Path')

$params.NewValue = Invoke-MyAlgorithm
```

There's clearly no one-size-fits-all solution; whichever approach you take depends on exactly what you're doing and what the requirements are.

The one thing in common is: build a hashtable of params, then splat it once<sup>*</sup>

<sup>* Exceptions apply :-p</sup>

Comment: This was an abbreviated example, there are usually more parameters than that, as well as variables that are derived while the script is executing that get passed into the command getting called. Is that going to change this example?    (RE: Url/Uri - Getting old sucks. Dont do it if you can. Distinguishing i from l, as well as commas and periods for some fonts gets hard)

Comment: O_O _Dude_, Thank You.